# How does Azure Function App Scale for millions of concurrent user request

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I am trying to understand how Azure function scales in traffic burst when running in either consumption plan or App Service plan. It says [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/) that one can have unlimited Web, Mobile, API App on App service plan.

Wondering how does it manage it? Specifically if I am running my function app in one of the app service plan, would it time out or unreachable at certain peak load condition?

Since there is only one IP address assigned to function app URI, how does Azure ensures the horizontal scaling in this case (extreme peak load condition)?

Is it using some sort of internal load-balancer and then creating a new temporary VM (to spread the load and) to run the instance of function app under load conditions (when certain number of concurrent users/connection trying to access the function URI)?

But even in that case wouldn't it run out the internal IPs for VM instances that get load balanced with internal load balancer? There must be a threshold point when the App service plan will run out of pool of internal IP to assign the VMs to scale out.

**So again how can one run unlimited web, mobile, API app on Azure app service plan considering this scenario without running out of any internal IP address pool?**

Comment: Side note: running out of even regular private 10.x.x.x IPv4 address range is hard, imagine how hard is to run out of IPv6 :)

Comment: There is considerable documentation, over many years, for Azure Web Apps (and Azure Functions). Unfortunately, your question is off-topic here, as the "how" is really a discussion, not a specific programming question (and much of the App Service architecture is already documented, so this is more of a documentation request question). That said: you're making some assumptions (like spinning up of temporary vm's, and eating up IP addresses) that really aren't accurate.

Comment: David appreciate if you can provide a link to the documentation on the internals of App Service plan which explains how it manages unlimited web, mobile app API and can scale to 10 M concurrent connection without running out of IP pools in a given Azure DC region. I have scanned through several docs and could not find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key question here is that how scaling works on an App Service Plan.

Azure Data centers consists of different scale units with each scale unit consisting of hundreds of servers (even 1000). This is the scaling power App Service brings with it. A single data center might have multiple Scale Units.

The internal architecture of an App Service consists of - 
Front End - A seven layer load balancer
Web Worker - Web Servers
File Servers - To Store Application content

To answer your below questions -

Q.Since there is only one IP address assigned to function app URI, how does Azure ensures the horizontal scaling in this case (extreme peak load condition)?

Q. Is it using some sort of internal load-balancer and then creating a new temporary VM (to spread the load and) to run the instance of function app under load conditions (when certain number of concurrent users/connection trying to access the function URI)?

**A : It does not create a new temporary VM but uses Web Workers which are pre-provisioned VMs running a shared load. Front end is a sever layered load balancer responsible for allocating traffic in case of horizontal scaling.**

But even in that case wouldn't it run out the internal IPs for VM instances that get load balanced with internal load balancer? There must be a threshold point when the App service plan will run out of pool of internal IP to assign the VMs to scale out.

**At the end of the day, a data center is limited by the amount of computing power available within. Hypothetically speaking, if a data center runs out computing capacity, in that scenario you might start experiencing timeouts as I am not aware of any scenario where an application will be scaled automatically to another region.**

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was expecting. As there is no such thing as Unlimited and this word in MS Doc is misleading. BTW, This is a real questions asked by my client and I went through all the architectural document on Azure on scalability and still could not figure out max limit under which App Service plan will start to crumble. My customer wants to run 1-2 M concurrent req on App Service using function. It would be nice if Microsoft provide the peak load of concurrent users each Azure App service plan can handle in every region so that we can plan any workaround better.